# Reduce JPEG image size without scale its width/height by Java

Tags: java, image, javax.imageio, reduce, jai

I want to reduce one jpeg image size(3M reduce to 1M) by Java, without scale(no change for image height and width). IN this site, I could not find a solution. Below is what I have tried:

**1 Using ImageIO:**

```
BufferedImage image  = ImageIO.read(inputFile);

ImageWriter writer = null;
Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");
if(iter.hasNext()){
    writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();
}

ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputFile);
writer.setOutput(ios);

ImageWriteParam iwParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
iwParam.setCompressionQuality(compressionQuality);
writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null ), iwParam);
```

For solution 1, I set compressionQuality for jpg but I can not obtain origina image compressQuality and the newImage I get sometimes is bigger than originals.

Answer (score 2):

The compression quality used is not stored with the JPEG image.

If you need to get below a certain threshold you must try several times while lowering the compression quality each time until you reach your limit.  Be aware that very low settings give bad images.

I am unfamiliar with the MODE_EXPLICIT flag.  It might also be a tunable parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. The MODE_EXPLICT MUST be set ...Yet, using ImageIO does not guarteen the size can be reduced, as you said, original Quality can not be detected... I used another way jai(http://www.coderanch.com/t/383601/java/java/decrease-size-jpeg-image-file) and it works..

Answer (score 1):

I found the [following](http://www.universalwebservices.net/web-programming-resources/java/adjust-jpeg-image-compression-quality-when-saving-images-in-java) code example for reducing the quality.

The important part is just to set iwp.setCompressionQuality. Hopes this helps.

```
BufferedImage bi = null;

bi = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));

Iterator iter = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) iter.next();

ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

// reduced quality.
iwp.setCompressionQuality(0.1f);

File file = new File("c:/image_low.jpg");

FileImageOutputStream output = null;

output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);

writer.setOutput(output);

IIOImage image = new IIOImage(bi, null, null);
writer.write(null, image, iwp);

writer.dispose();
```

Comment: This is the same as what I post above. Set CompressionQuality =0.1 would achive highest compress but decrease too much quality.. I have found another solution from coderanch.com/t/383601/java/java/decrease-size-jpeg-image-file  but I have not fond how it works yet.